# Puppet configuration for apache2 with mod_headers

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, vagrant, puppet, mod-headers

I'm configuring a Vagrant box (Ubuntu) with a puppet manifest - Everything is working except when I visit a site on the Vagrant host I get an error:

```
Invalid command 'Header'
```

Which I believe is due to Apache's mod_header not being loaded. The puppet manifest for apache2 is simple:

```
class { 'apache2':
    document_root => '/path/to/docroot',
}
```

How do I tell puppet to provision the Vagrant box to enable mod_headers?

Comment: What apache module are you using? This does not look like `puppetlabs-apache`.

Comment: When the Vagrant machine is provisioned, it looks like it's loading a default puppet module:   puppet.module_path    = "puppet/modules" that contains the apache configuration. Thx

Comment: So is this a premade `vagrant` config you downloaded somewhere? I'm interested in the source of `puppet/modules/apache2`, for that is key to your answer.

Comment: Yes - from here: https://github.com/matthewsplant/magento-vagrant-puppet

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate - the author included a custom `apache2` module that does not give you the option to include modules. You could try and replace `modules/apache2` with a clone of https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache. If you change your question into "how to do that", I shall try and come up with a simple answer.

Comment: Thanks Felix - appreciate the deep dive.

Answer (score 0):

If the module provided in the vagrant config is not appropriate for your needs, I suggest you add and use the [official apache module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache). Install it into `puppet/modules`.

Instead of `class { 'apache2': document_root => '/path/to/docroot' }`, configure apache with the new module as follows:

```
include apache

# keep using original template for simplicity's sake
file { '/etc/apache2/sites-available/default':
    ensure => file,
    content => template('apache2/vhost_default.erb'),
}

# activate mod_headers
include apache::mod::headers
```